# The order of listview items is jumbled up when listview is updated in android

Tags: android

I've a listview in my app and when i try to update the listview its showing the strange behavior. The list view items are showing in random order when i try to input any new contact in the list.

First three methods are of different class.

```
   public void selectContact()
   {
    //code
    Contact cn=new Contact(name, number, type, true, true);
    addContactToList(cn);

   }

   public void addContactToList(Contact cn)
        {
            CallBlockerMainActivity.List.put(cn.getNumber(), cn);

            updateListData();
        }

    public static void updateListData()
        {
            ArrayList<Contact>list2=new ArrayList<Contact>();
            list2.addAll(CallBlockerMainActivity.List.values());

            ContactAdapter adapter=new ContactAdapter(instance, list2);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

This is the listview adapter code.

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Contact>contacts;

    public ContactAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Contact>contacts)
    {
        this.activity=activity;
        this.contacts=contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return contacts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView == null) 
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null);
            }

            final Contact cn=contacts.get(position);

            TextView name=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.listNameTxt);
            TextView number=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.listNumberTxt);

            name.setText(cn.getName());
            number.setText(cn.getNumber());
    }

}
```

Comment: Define all your views of adapter class in holder class

Comment: can u explain or give example.

Comment: Check this http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: Did the changes but no help!

Comment: Can I see your changes?

Comment: Actually i've removed the changes now.....can u make the changes in above code

Comment: whats `CallBlockerMainActivity.List` ?

Comment: List is static hash map variable of callblockeermainactivity class